# Use an InputObjectType instance as Input for relay mutation

Tags: python, graphql, relay, graphene-python

According to the Graphene Documentation, if we are to get input from the user when implementing `relay.clientIDMutation`, then it needs to be under the Input subclass like so:

```
class Foo(relay.clientIDMuation):
  class Input:
    arg1 = graphene.String()
    arg2 = graphene.Sring()

# the return parameters and mutate and get payload method after this
```

But, we can also specify InputObjectTypes.

```
class Bar(graphene.InputObjectType):
  arg1 = graphene.String()
  arg2 = graphene.String()
```

And if we were to use a normal graphene mutation object you could use specify input in the Arguments subclass.

```
class NewFoo(graphene.Mutation):
  class Arguments:
    input = Bar()

  # return arguments and mutate method after this
```

How can `Bar` an `InputObjectType` be used for the Input attribute in the NewFoo mutation when it inherits from `relay.clientIDMutation` while still being able to pass the clientMutationID as an argument of input?

```
class NewFoo(relay.clientIDMutation):
  class Attribute:
    input = Foo()

# the return parameters and mutate and get payload method after this
```

**Note**: I have already tried adding an Arguments subclass with an input attribute like above, but that did not work when the class inherits from `relay.clientIDMuation`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `class Attribute:` with `relay.clientIDMutation` class.

Try this. Declare this class before initiating you relay class.

```
class Bar(graphene.InputObjectType):
   arg1 = graphene.String()
   arg2 = graphene.String()
```

Inside your relay class,

```
class NewFoo(relay.clientIDMutation):
   class Input:
   inputarray = Foo()
```

Your Mutation should look something like this,

```
mutation{
  NewFoo(input:{
      inputarray:{
        arg1:"Hello"
        arg2:"world"
        }
      }
    )
 }
```

Although you still won't be able to pass an array of inputs to this field.

Comment: Sorry for the really late response, but I ended up doing something really similar. Seems like there should be a method to directly mention the input type in the Mutation. Anyways, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AbstractType`

```
class Bar(graphene.AbstractType):
    arg1 = graphene.String()
    arg2 = graphene.String()

class NewFoo(relay.clientIDMutation):
    Input = Bar

    # Other Code
```

With this you can get properly input

```
mutation{
NewFoo(input:{
      arg1:"Hello"
      arg2:"world"
    }
  )
}
```

**EDIT:**

From 2.0 version AbstractType is deprecated:

You just have to create the class

```
class Bar:
    arg1 = graphene.String()
    arg2 = graphene.String()
```